# Keep menu toggle state after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here’s a toggle menu who works perfectly: 
If I click on the link (HTML code below), the menu folds. But I want if the users reload the page to keep the state of menu (expand / collapse).

```js
    $('#menu_toggle').click(function () {
        if ($('body').hasClass('nav-md')) {
            $('body').removeClass('nav-md');
            $('body').addClass('nav-sm');
            $('.left_col').removeClass('scroll-view');
            $('.left_col').removeAttr('style');
            $('.sidebar-footer').hide();

            if ($('#sidebar-menu li').hasClass('active')) {
                $('#sidebar-menu li.active').addClass('active-sm');
                $('#sidebar-menu li.active').removeClass('active');
            }
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('nav-sm');
            $('body').addClass('nav-md');
            $('.sidebar-footer').show();

            if ($('#sidebar-menu li').hasClass('active-sm')) {
                $('#sidebar-menu li.active-sm').addClass('active');
                $('#sidebar-menu li.active-sm').removeClass('active-sm');
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

How to remember the state?
Full project: http://demo.kimlabs.com/gentelella/production/index.html
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sort of thing I'd use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for. Just set some kind of flag in localStorage when the state changes and fetch it when your page loads.

I should add that using css classes to represent view state isn't a good idea and will bite you if your UI gets much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use cookies to store booleans, of if the menu has been opened or closed. Then when a page is loaded, it checks for any stored cookies, and by default uses those variables.

**For example:**

on page load:

```
var menuOutBoolean = Cookies.get("menuOutB") || false;
if (menuOutBoolean == true || menuOutBoolean == "true"){
    //put the menu out
}
else {
    //put menu in
}
```

On change:

```
if (/*out*/){
    Cookies.set("menuOutB","true");
}
else{
    Cookies.set("menuOutB","false");
}
```

**Note:**
Here I have used [this JavaScript API (Jquery Plugin)](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

Comment: Any code that is of the form `if (condition) { true } else { false }` can be rewritten as just `condition` — here, your code could be simply `Cookies.set("menuOutB", out)` where "out" is a boolean variable, a function that returns a boolean, or a test condition that evaluates to a boolean. Example: `Cookies.set("menuOutB", $("menu").hasClass("open"))`